# Which class will trigger first in PostAuthenticateRequest event

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, httpmodule

I have folder HttpModules where i have :

- SomeKindOfAuthenticateHttpModule.cs,
- GetApplicationVersionHttpModule.cs,

Both classes implement interface IHttpModule.

I wanna trigger in both classes OnPostAuthenticateRequest() event,

In first class it will check if user is authenticated,

In second class it will check if user is running optimal application version,

Now i would love to know, which class will go first ?

```
Will it first authenticate and then check app version,
```

OR

```
Will it first check app version or authenticate?
```

Am i able to manipulate this somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,

All depends which one i put first in Web.Config

For example :

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add name="I_Will_Trigger_First" />
  <add name="I_Will_Trigger_Second" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```